# Creating a Rails app in workspace directory of Cloud9 IDE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cloud9-ide

When I run `rails new .` hoping to create a new Rails app in my workspace directory, `rails` says:

```
Invalid application name 567101. Please give a name that does not start with numbers.
```

How do I get around this? I could just create it *within* the top level directory, but that seems inelegant. When you create a workspace and select "Rails" for the type it sets up the app nicely in the right place, but I want to set up a Rails 4 app, so that's not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just trying to figure this out myself. What I ended up doing is creating a symbolic link to the numbered directory named rails_app. I was then able to do a rails new and have it create the application.

First

```
cd ~/
```

Then

```
ln -s ./567101 ./rails_app
```

Then

```
rails new ./rails_app
```